# Sound notification over SSH

Tags: notification, irssi

I just switched from the Konversation IRC client to the terminal based IRSSI. I'm starting IRSSI on a remote machine using GNU screen + SSH. I do not get any sound notification on new messages, which means that I've to check out IRSSI once in a while for new messages.

That's not really productive, so I'm looking for an application / script that plays a sound (preferably `/usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg` and not the annoying beep) on my machine if there is any activity. It would be great if I can disable the notification for certain channels.

Or, if that's not possible, some sort of notification via `libnotify`, thus making it available to GNOME and KDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not like libnotify, so I created an UDP server in Python and a client application for irssi. Note that this answer applies to the original requirements in [revision 1](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/57035/1), it does not have text notification.

#### Client

This version reacts to various messages directed at you. If you would like to be notified of messages in any channel, remove the leading `#` in the `#'message public'` line. Some rate-limiting is implemented, there will be at least 1.3 seconds delay between notifications.

```
##
## Put me in ~/.irssi/scripts, and then execute the following in irssi:
##
##       /load perl
##       /script load notifyudp
##

use strict;
use Irssi;
use IO::Socket;
use vars qw($VERSION %IRSSI);
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

$VERSION = "0.3.20140930";
%IRSSI = (
    authors     => 'Lekensteyn',
    contact     => 'lekensteyn@gmail.com',
    name        => 'notifyudp.pl',
    description => 'Send a UDP signal to a remote machine',
    license     => 'GPLv3+'
);

Irssi::settings_add_str('notifyudp', 'notifyudp_ip_addr', '');
# port 0 = disabled
Irssi::settings_add_int('notifyudp', 'notifyudp_port', 0);
Irssi::settings_add_bool('notifyudp', 'notifyudp_auto_start', 0);

my $sock;

sub notify_load {
    if ($sock) {
        Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: Already connected.');
        return;
    }
    my $ip = Irssi::settings_get_str('notifyudp_ip_addr');
    my $port = Irssi::settings_get_int('notifyudp_port');
    if (!$port || !$ip) {
        Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: No port or host set, /set notifyudp for more information..');
        return;
    }
    if ($port < 1024 || $port > 65535) {
        Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: Invalid port, must be 1024 <= port <= 65535, resetting and ignoring.');
        Irssi::settings_set_int('notifyudp_port', 0);
        return;
    }
    $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(
        PeerAddr => $ip,
        PeerPort => $port,
        Proto => 'udp',
        Timeout => 1
    );
    Irssi::print("NotifyUDP: IP $ip will be notified on port $port.");
}

my $last_time = 0;
sub notify {
    if ($sock) {
        my $now = time;
        my $notify_delay = 1.3;
        if (abs($now - $last_time) > $notify_delay) {
            $last_time = $now;
            $sock->send("M");
        }
    }
}
sub notify_if_hilighted {
    my ($dest, $text, $stripped) = @_;
    if ($dest->{level} & MSGLEVEL_HILIGHT) {
        notify();
    }
}

sub notify_stop {
    if ($sock) {
        Irssi::print("NotifyUDP: Stopping.");
        $sock->send("S");
        $sock = undef;
    } else {
        Irssi::print("NotifyUDP: not active.");
    }
}

sub cmd_notifyudp {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    if ($cmd eq 'start') {
        notify_load();
    } elsif ($cmd eq 'stop') {
        notify_stop();
    } elsif ($cmd eq 'ping') {
        notify();
    } else {
        Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: Usage: /notifyudp [start|stop|ping]');
    }
}

Irssi::command_bind('notifyudp', 'cmd_notifyudp');

my @signals = (
# Uncomment the following to get notifs for every (channel) message
#'message public',
'message private',
'dcc request',

'message irc notice', # NickServ responses and such

# whenever the server dies
'server connected',
'server connect failed',
'server disconnected',

'message invite',
'message topic',
'message dcc',
'ctcp msg',
'ctcp reply',
);
Irssi::signal_add('print text', 'notify_if_hilighted');
foreach (@signals) {
    Irssi::signal_add($_, 'notify');
}

if (Irssi::settings_get_bool('notifyudp_auto_start')) {
    Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: automatic connection with the sound server is enabled.');
    notify_load();
} else {
    Irssi::print('NotifyUDP: automatic connection with the sound server is disabled.');
}
```

#### Server

When started, it listens on all addresses, port 3533. If it receives a UDP packet "M", it plays `/usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg` using `paplay` ("PulseAudio play"). On receiving `S`, it quits the server. Since it's open-source, you are free to remove this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# udpsoundserver.py

"""Listen on a UDP port and play a sound when 'M' is received

Starts the server listening on UDP port PORT (3533 by default) on address HOST
(by default all addresses). Valid commands are:
M - play Music
S - Stop the server
"""
try:
    import socketserver
except ImportError:
    import SocketServer as socketserver
from os import system,getpid
import threading
import sys

# leave it empty to listen on all addresses
HOST = ""
PORT = 3533


class UDPSvr(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0]
        if sys.version >= '3':
            data = str(data, "ISO-8859-1")
        data = data.strip()
        if data == "M":
            ding.dong()
        elif data == "S":
            ding.die()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
    def run(self):
        server.serve_forever();

class Handler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.play = False
        self.must_die = False

    def run(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        while True:
            self.event.wait(1.)
            if self.event.isSet():
                if self.play:
                    print("Playing...")
                    system("paplay /usr/share/sounds/KDE-Im-Irc-Event.ogg")
                # no else if to allow shutdown signals 
                if self.must_die:
                    print("Shutting down...")
                    server.shutdown()
                    break
                self.play = False
                self.event.clear()

    def dong(self):
        self.play = True
        self.event.set()

    def die(self):
        self.must_die = True
        self.event.set()

def ca(num, x):
    print("Caught SIGINT, shutting down...")
    ding.die()

import signal
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("My PID is: " + str(getpid()))

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        HOST = sys.argv[1]
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        PORT = int(sys.argv[2])

    print("Host: " + HOST)
    print("Port: " + str(PORT))
    server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), UDPSvr)

    ding = Handler()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ca)
    worker = Worker()
    ding.start()
    worker.start()
    # might not be the cleanest, but it allows Ctrl + C
    while ding.isAlive():
        ding.join(3600)
```

The sequence of starting the remote server becomes:

```
screen -dm path/to/udpsoundserver.py
ssh -R 5355:localhost:5355
```

After logging in, I run:

```
screen -t irssi irssi
```

Should you need to reconnect later:

```
screen -r irssi
```

After starting `irssi`, you need to set the host and port:

```
/set notifyudp_ip_addr 127.0.0.1
/set notifyudp_port 5355
```

To make it connect automatically on startup:

```
/set notifyudp_auto_start 1
```

The first time, you need to start Notify UDP manually since it was not auto started yet:

```
/notifyudp start
```

In order to test the notification:

```
/notifyudp ping
```

To-do:

- make the soundserver stop on disconnect
- allow for skipping channels

Comment: You said that text indicator was not a requirement - the phrasing implied that it would be nice, but wasn't the preferred option. I apologize for the edit, and you can roll it back if you want.

Comment: No problem, it's good to have alternatives. My solution is as I said hacked together, so your answer may be worth trying.

Answer (score 7):

I do this with libnotify. I found [this](http://thorstenl.blogspot.com/2007/01/thls-irssi-notification-script.html) ages ago.

It works like a champ. I used to use it with libnotify on linux (and still do when I'm on a linux machine) but most of the time I'm on a macbook now, so I use growl as a replacement for libnotify on the mac.

```
# todo: grap topic changes

use strict;
use vars qw($VERSION %IRSSI);

use Irssi;
$VERSION = '0.0.3';
%IRSSI = (
    authors     => 'Thorsten Leemhuis',
    contact     => 'fedora@leemhuis.info',
    name        => 'fnotify',
    description => 'Write a notification to a file that shows who is talking to you in which channel.',
    url         => 'http://www.leemhuis.info/files/fnotify/',
    license     => 'GNU General Public License',
    changed     => '$Date: 2007-01-13 12:00:00 +0100 (Sat, 13 Jan 2007) $'
);

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# In parts based on knotify.pl 0.1.1 by Hugo Haas
# http://larve.net/people/hugo/2005/01/knotify.pl
# which is based on osd.pl 0.3.3 by Jeroen Coekaerts, Koenraad Heijlen
# http://www.irssi.org/scripts/scripts/osd.pl
#
# Other parts based on notify.pl from Luke Macken
# http://fedora.feedjack.org/user/918/
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Private message parsing
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

sub priv_msg {
    my ($server,$msg,$nick,$address,$target) = @_;
    filewrite($nick." " .$msg );
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Printing hilight's
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

sub hilight {
    my ($dest, $text, $stripped) = @_;
    if ($dest->{level} & MSGLEVEL_HILIGHT) {
    filewrite($dest->{target}. " " .$stripped );
    }
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# The actual printing
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

sub filewrite {
    my ($text) = @_;
    # FIXME: there is probably a better way to get the irssi-dir...
        open(FILE,">>$ENV{HOME}/.irssi/fnotify");
    print FILE $text . "\n";
        close (FILE);
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Irssi::signal_add_last / Irssi::command_bind
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

Irssi::signal_add_last("message private", "priv_msg");
Irssi::signal_add_last("print text", "hilight");

#- end
```

To load it in `irssi`, run the following:

`/load perl`

`/script load fnotify`

Then, we need to get it routed to `libnotify`. To do that, save the following as a shell script and run it on login:

```
# yes, we need a way to flush the file on disconnect; i don't know one
# yes, that's flush is not atomic (but good enough for me)
ssh remote.system.somewhere "tail -n 10 .irssi/fnotify ; : > .irssi/fnotify ; tail -f .irssi/fnotify " | sed -u 's/[<@&]//g' | while read heading message  do  notify-send -i gtk-dialog-info -t 300000 -- "${heading}" "${message}"; done # the sed -u 's/[<@&]//g' is needed as those characters might confuse  notify-send (FIXME: is that a bug or a feature?)
```

Comment: Lame GROWLer. ;) I'll take a look.

Comment: I'll check this later, a day after posting this Q I hacked a perl and python script together which I've been using then.